# rewrite get request htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following htaccess rule

```
Options All -Indexes 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^welcome/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?\.html$ welcome.php?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

This works fine for the welcome.php page and the 3 lang=(de/en/it), but only if i'm typing in the URL in the browser address bar.

If i'm switching from the language form, the GET request will be appended to the rewritten URL like

```
 welcome/de.html?lang=de
```

How can i rewrite the GET requests so the URL will be

```
 welcome/en.html
```

and not

```
welcome/de.html?lang=en
```

Also, is it possible to apply a general rule for all pages and not only for the welcome site.

Thanks in advance for helping

**EDIT**

Now my htaccess file is

```
Options All -Indexes 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(welcome)[^?]*\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^/%1/%2.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^welcome/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?\.html$ welcome.php?lang=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^welcome/([\w-]+)/?\.html$ welcome.php?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

But it's still not working. The GET query string is still appended like

```
  welcome/de.html?lang=de
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need these 2 additional rules:

```
Options All -Indexes 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(test/[^/.?]+)[^?]*\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2.html? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^welcome/([\w-]+)/?\.html$ welcome.php?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: No sorry I included your rule also as 2nd rule. So just insert my first rule before your rule.

Comment: Can you see my Edit in the question please? And, hot to apply a rule for all the files, e.g. welcome, index,contact, ecc.?

Comment: Still not working. I can't understand why :-(.Maybe because my action is `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>` But i also tried with PHP_SELF but it's still the same. Also, is there a possibility to apply the working rule for all pages, e.g. welcome, contact, someotherpage, ecc.?

Comment: This rule works for all this URLs already. Which URL is not showing properly for you?

Comment: Sure the url is working, but only if i type it in the address bar. With the language switcher there's no way to get the right url. The GET query string is always appended to the rewritten URL

Comment: What is that full URL that shows in browser address bar with get string?

Comment: with the rewritten rule `http://localhost/test/welcome/en.html?lang=it`. Without the .htaccess it is `http://localhost/test/welcome?lang=de`.

Comment: Ok will test in an hour when I get back to my computer

Comment: You didn't mention presence of `/test/` folder before which cause rule to not to work. Try above rules in `/test/.htaccess` file now

Comment: Sorry. I thought it's nearly the same. Also, i didn't mention it because online the site is in the webroot. I've tested your rule in localhost and now i got a **Not found ERROR**. When i'm using the switching menu the URL in the address bar is `http://localhost/test/test/welcome/de.html` because of the rewrite base.

Answer (score 0):

Idea:

1. Rewrite `welcome/de.html?lang=en` to `welcome/en.html` (make sure this rule does NOT have [L] flag)
2. Rewrite `welcome/en.html` to `welcome.php?lang=en`

You only need one rule for #1:

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^welcome\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?\.html\?lang=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ welcome/$2.html [QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^welcome\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?\.html$ welcome.php?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Rule #1: http://regex101.com/r/rX2gG5

Rule #2: http://regex101.com/r/aD3mV2

Comment: The idea is good but unfortunately it's not working :-). Something is wrong with your example. The GET query string is still appended if i am switching the language.

Comment: In your first rule the "lang" is missing. But if i write `RewriteRule ^welcome/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?\.html\?lang=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ welcome/$1.html [QSA,NC]` i get an 500 error.

Comment: Edited. Not only `lang` was missing, but it should have been `welcome/$2.html` instead of `welcome/$1.html`, which should cause loop.

Comment: Now the GET query string is still appended and i get a nasty "internal server error" :-(. I was thinking about some `{THE_REQUEST}` in your code but i don't know how to rewrite your rule.

Comment: Rewrote patterns. Now they are correctly escaped. I assumed your patterns were valid, but regex checker told otherwise :/

Comment: Right patterns or not, still not working. So i will resign after days of searching the right patterns and trying out all possible combination. Thanks anyway for trying to help and thanks for the regex.101.com link. Useful site.